# How do return a Constant Value in the Sql Else Clause when only on value remain's the same

Tags: t-sql, triggers

```
UPDATE  ConcordWholesales_new.dbo.Product 
SET CCCQTYINSTOCK=isnull(@newQTYINSTOCK,'')    
where SKU=@newSTOCKCODE   

UPDATE  Product 
SET Published = CASE WHEN CCCQTYINSTOCK=isnull(@newQTYINSTOCK,'') 
    THEN '1' ELSE 0 END
```

I have an Update Trigger that Update's Stock Quantity's when its below 0 the Product becomes Unpublished. If the StockQuantity goes above 0 the above Case Updates the Published feild to republish the Product.

When I update the ELSE clause returns a 0 value on the other columns, but If I remove the ELSE clause it can't insert a null value.

How do I return the above code so it only Updates one line of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were missing `WHERE` clause in second statement

```
UPDATE  Product 
SET Published = CASE WHEN CCCQTYINSTOCK > 0
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
where SKU=@newSTOCKCODE
```

and one more thing, what datatype is Published column ?
you are using '1' - its nchar, and 0 - int